# CSV import not updating attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

I am trying to run CSV import using Dataflow Profiles, it shows import ran successfully and records updated, but when I check the product in admin its not updating many attributes but not giving any error, I tried to run magento's simple import, there the same CSV file says duplicate column name while I cant find any duplicate titles in my csv. I couldn't find a way to upload CSV here, so pasting just first 2 rows here

```
store,websites,attribute_set,prodtype,category_ids,sku,has_options,name,meta_title,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,url_key,url_path,config_attributes,custom_design,page_layout,options_container,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,gift_message_available,no_of_solitires,solitaire_weight,solitaire_quality,setting_type,total_diamond_weight,diamond_quality,height,width,total_diamonds,length,diamond_setting_type,solitaire_setting_type,solitaire_color,solitaire_certificatetype,solitaire_certificateno,shipping_time,price,special_price,weight,msrp,status,is_recurring,visibility,tax_class_id,ringsize,metal,purity,diamond_shape,solitaire_shape,mine,chaintype,metalktcol,confmine,confmetalktcol,default_configuration_id,description,short_description,meta_keyword,custom_layout_update,special_from_date,special_to_date,news_from_date,news_to_date,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,stock_status_changed_automatically,use_config_enable_qty_increments,product_name,store_id,product_type_id,product_status_changed,product_changed_websites,product_id,gallery,minimal_price,gallery_label,stonecentercolor,associated,related,upsell,crosssell,tier_prices,bundle_options,grouped,group_price_price,downloadable_options,downloadable_sample_options,super_attribute_pricing,product_tags,old_id,recurring_profile,Ring Size:drop_down:1:0,listmine,listclarity,lay01metalktcol,lay01stntype,lay01stnshape,lay01stnsetting,lay01gender,lay01occassion,jewlength,jewwidth,jewheight,jewdiamete,prodengshankwidth,stonecentertitle,stonecentertype,stonecentershape,stonecentercolor,stonecenterclarity,stonecenterqty,stonecenterweight,stonecentersetting,stonecentersize,stonecentercertno,stonecentercerttype,metal01title,metal01type,metal01kt,metal01col,metal01ktcol,metal01weight,metal02title,metal02type,metal02kt,metal02col,metal02ktcol,metal02weight,prodneckhaintype,prodneckchainkt,prodneckchainlength,prodneckchainweight,prodneckclasptype,prodearbacking
default,base,Default,simple,"3,6,32",BD22393-14WH-SI-AG,0,BD22393-14WH-SI-AG -Try,BD22393,,/ImageAll/BD22393_WhWh-Main.jpg,/ImageAll/BD22393_WhWh-Main.jpg,/ImageAll/BD22393_WhWh-Main.jpg,,,,levelup/default,1 column,Product Info Column,,,,,Use config,Use config,No,,,,Channel Setting,0.14 carat,SI2,,,13,,,,,,,,319.99,,,,Enabled,No,Not Visible Individually,Shipping,,gold,14KT,Round,,Argyle,,,Argyle,14k White Gold,,"bridal-collection Band set in 14KT White Gold with  Diamonds (0.14 ct, SI2)",Bridal Band in 14KT White Gold with Diamonds (0.14 ct),,,,,,,,,5,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,BD22393-14WH-SI-AG,1,simple,,,,"/ImageAll/BD22393_WhWh-Main.jpg,/ImageAll/BD22393_WhWh-Other.jpg,/ImageAll/BD22393_OnHand.jpg",,,H-I,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Argyle,SI2,14K WHITE GOLD,DIAMOND,ROUND CUT,CHANNEL SET,FEMALE,"ANNIVERSARY,WEDDING,BIRTHDAY,GIFT",,,,,,DIAMOND DETAILS,DIAMOND,ROUND CUT,HI,SI2,13,0.14 carat,CHANNEL SET,,,,METAL DETAILS,GOLD,14KT GOLD,WHITE GOLD,14KT WHITE GOLD,,,,,,,,,14KT,,,,
```

The attributes I am monitoring for change are:

metal01title
metal01type
metal01kt
metal01col
metal01ktcol
stonecenterclarity
stonecenterqty

Looking for help from experts here, TIA

Answer (score 0):

Create file reindex.php and add this code

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';  
 $app = Mage::app('admin');  
 umask(0);  
 for ($index = 1; $index <= 8; $index++) {  
     $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($index);  
     $process->reindexAll();  
 }
```

then your all attribute re-index

hope your helpful this code

Comment: I had already tried reindexing but that didn't help.